# Unable to write a reference to LoginComponent in C:/Users/lib/pages/login/login.component.ts from C:/Users/lib/users.module.ts

Tags: angular, deployment, compiler-errors, ng-build

I'm trying to build the application but another error came up... I've checked the app and it's working. Also looked up on the internet for several days and tried all of the methods people used and it's still giving me the error... Please help! Thank you in advance!
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjLZV.png)

Comment: can you a code snippet of your login component and module?

Comment: Hi nimeresam, thanks for your reply. I've solved the issue because I had circular dependencies in my shared library so I have moved the files and the error disappeared.